# git remote push origin changed and cannot reset

Tags: git, github

Here's currently what `git remote -v` says:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:me/myrepo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:zendframework/zend-i18n.git (push)
```

I have no idea why `zend-il8n` is now the default push origin.

I've tried:

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://github.com/me/myrepo.git
```

As well as:

```
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:me/myrepo.git
```

How do I reset the push origin to my repo as the fetch origin is at.

*** ALSO ***

If theres a simpler way to push explicitly to a repo without the configuration url i might be interested in that approach and then re-cloning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

`git remote rename origin origin-old`

`git remote add origin git@github.com:me/myrepo.git`

If that solves the problem then you can do:

`git remote remove origin-old`

Hope this helps!